# What's the best way to pass specific parameters to a method

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am writing a C# components that gathers information from the input parameters and returns the gathered information in a dictionary like this : Dictionary. The current method signature looks like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> GenerateAliquotLabel(EAliquoteLabelOptions fieldsToAdd, AliquoteLabelGeneratorParameters parameters)
```

The parameters parameter contains all the sources from which information is returned. The keys in the dictionary that I return are currently generated internally.

The problem is that now I want to specify the keys in the dictionary that I return as parameters and I do not know any elegant ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your option is params.

```
public Dictionary<string, object> GenerateAliquotLabel(params string[] parameters);
```

Then you can use that method similar to String.Format() for example:

```
var output = Generator.GenerateAliquotLabel("BlueLabel", "RedLabel", "SmallLabel");
```